# Add simple quote into an if statement

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, visual-studio, null

I would like to compare UserName and Pass entered by an user with me Local Database.

When I Tried to request on my database, I saw I had to put simple quotes into my request, such as

```
SELECT * FROM Administrator
WHERE UserName = 'FSelva';
```

The problem is, when I check the database, I do it like that:

```
if((username == admin.UserName) && (password == admin.Pass))
        {
            this.Close();
            MainPage retourpageprincipale = new MainPage();
            retourpageprincipale.Show();
        }
        else
        {
```

Admin.**** is the database ones and username & password are variables which catch what the user entered.

When I'm doing step by step, admin.UserName is Null, such as admin.Pass.

I think adding simple quotes like:

```
if((username == "'" && admin.UserName && "'") && (password == "'" && admin.Pass && "'"))
```

could fix my problem. But I can't do like this.

Is anybody knows what's the syntax please?

edit:

This is the entire code:

```
namespace WpfApplication3
{
    public partial class Window1 : Window
    {
        private Database1Entities1 conn = new Database1Entities1();
        public Window1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void ConnectionClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var username = UserNameBox.Text;
            var password = PasswordBox.Text;
            con.Database.Connection.Open();

            Administrator admin = new Administrator();

            if((username == admin.UserName) && (password == admin.Pass))
            {
                this.Close();
                MainPage retourpageprincipale = new MainPage();
                retourpageprincipale.Show();
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Combo Admin/Password non valide!
            }
```

Where Administrator is my admin table:

```
public partial class Administrator
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Pass { get; set; }
    public bool IsSuperAdmin { get; set; }
}
```

When I Step by Step this code, at line:

```
if((username == admin.UserName) && (password == admin.Pass))
```

username value is RSans (what I wrote into the IHM)
password valus is 1234abcd (What I wrote into the IHM)
admin.UserName valus is Null
admin.Pass is Null.

Moreover,
admin value is WpfApplication3.Administrator
conn value is WpfApplication3.Database1Entities1

If you need some others informations, i'll edit my post again.

Edit2:

This is my Database1Entities1 full code:

```
namespace WpfApplication3
{
    using System;
    using System.Data.Entity;
    using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;
public partial class Database1Entities1 : DbContext
{
    public Database1Entities1()
        : base("name=Database1Entities1")
        {
        }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
    }
    public DBSet<Administrator> Administrator { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Can you show the code that creates the admin object and the code that makes the database call?

Comment: The syntax would be a + instead of &&, but that should not solve this problem.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? _should_ `admin.UserName` be null at that point?

Comment: Post edited, I think I've answered to your questions.   @JohnSaunders: When I'm trying to achieve is a simple administrator login with a local database. The user enter his username and password into a basic IHM, I check if the username/password exist into the database and log in if it is.

Comment: Generally, this comparison would be made _in_ the database, not in your code.

Comment: Am I supposed to use LinQ to perform this? Have you got some link that I could see to understand what you mean?
Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in your code lies by reading the Information from the database. If both admin.* properties are null, it means that they are either null in the database or you don't set them properly.
Furtermore, you do not need simple quotes. They are used in SQL to show that the cell is of type string. Once you read the information to an object in C#, you will see that the quotes are gone. It is easiest to debug your code and step from line to line to see what is wrong.

### Update

Since you are using Entity Framework, here is how you can retrieve information from the Database:

Your `Database1Entities1` is the so called DbContext. You can use it to query the database. It should have a property `Administrators`. If it doesn't, you can add the following part to the `Database1Entities1` class:

```
public DbSet<Administrator> Administrators { get; set; }
```

You can then use the your conn object to query the database, e.g.

```
var admin = conn.Administrators.SingleOrDefault(a => a.UserName == "FSelva");
```

Since you are already querying the database, you could add the whole check (including the password) in one step:

```
var admin = conn.Administrators.SingleOrDefault(a => a.UserName == "FSelva" && a.Password == "...");
// if there is no match, the admin object will be NULL here
```

### Update 2

You do not need to open the connection manually. Entity Framework will do that for you. So you can delete the line:

```
con.Database.Connection.Open();
```

Comment: I understand what you mean, but.. When I Open the Server Explorer and I do "Show Table Data" into my Administrator table, I see the informations I entered before: UserName: FSelva Pass: abcd1234 IsSuperAdmin: False    And     UserName: RSans  Pass: 1234abcd IsSuperAdmin: True

My table Administrator isn't empty.

I understand for the simple quotes. So my problem is different: why I don't succeed to check my Administrator's values. when I compare'em with the user prompt.

Comment: You are creating a new instance of the Administrator class by doing 'Administrator admin = new Administrator();'. What you need to do instead of this line is to read the information from the database. Only opening the connection is not enough. If you tell me which database technology you are using (e.g. Entity Framework), I can provide you a small snippet.

Comment: Thanks a lot WeSt. I'm using Entity Framework technology. I have created a Service-based database called Database1.mdf, then I have created an ADO.NET Entity Data Model called Model1.edmx
If you need any other information.

Comment: Visual Studio tells me: "The type or namespace name 'DbSet' could not be found". Have I to add any Reference maybe?

Comment: Please post the full code of your Database1Entities1 class.

Comment: The Database1Entities1 class already contains a DBSet, so you don't need to add it. You can use this to query the database (just look at my code). It should go with conn.Administrator.SingleOrDefault(...). And you have a Typo as well: it is called DbSet, not DBSet.

Comment: I have done a step by step debug and I have found one problem: When I underline      var admin = conn.Administrators.SingleOrDefault(a => a.UserName == "FSelva" && a.Password == "abcd1234");     (which match with the database), admin is still Null.

Comment: I haven't said anything, it works!!
I have just edited the line var admin = conn.Administrators.SingleOrDefault(a => a.UserName == "FSelva" && a.Password == "abcd1234")     by    var admin = conn.Administrators.SingleOrDefault(a => a.UserName == username && a.Password == password)